# Compactness And Boundedness Of Metric Spaces

Tags: real-analysis

I have read in Rudin's Analysis that a metric space $X$ with the property that every infinite subset has a limit point is compact. Then I want to know that this property holds for any bounded metric space from Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem And hence every bounded metric space should be compact but this is not true.
$$$$Can Someone Help??

Comment: Your second sentence is written in a very confusing way. In any case, it seems as though you didn't understand what exactly the Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem is about. In particular, Bolzano-Weierstrass is specific to metric spaces that are subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ (or subsets of $\Bbb R$ depending on your textbook). Note that there are metric spaces that cannot be thought of in this way.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to understand your question, but I think the crux is that you are surprised by the fact that there are bounded metric spaces that fail to be compact. So to that end, here are two examples of relatively simple metric spaces that are bounded but not compact.

**Example 1:** Consider the metric space $X_1 = (0,1) \subset \Bbb R$ with the usual metric. The set $S_1 = \{ 1/n : n = 1,2,3,\dots\}$ is infinite. Accordingly, if we consider $S \subset \Bbb R$, then we find that the set has a limit point. However, $S_1 \subset X_1$ does not have a limit point because there is no point *inside the space $X_1$* that has the property of a limit point.

**Example 2:** Consider the metric space $X_2 = \Bbb R$ with the metric $d$ defined by $d(x,y) = \min\{|x-y|,1\}$. Note that $X_2$ is bounded relative to this metric.  The set $S_2 = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$ is a (bounded) subset of $X$ but fails to have a limit point.

Answer (score 0):

Bolzano-Weiertrass does not say that any sequence of a bounded subset has a limit point *in the subset*.

For exemple, consider in $\mathbb{R}$, the sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ of $(0,1]$ defined by
$$x_n= \frac{1}{n}$$

Of course it has a limit point in $\mathbb{R}$ (a unique one, which is $0$), but it has no limit point in $(0,1]$.